# Variable access from Form1 to From2

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to C# and I need to be able to access a declared variable from Form1 to Form2. Variable example:

`decimal Total = 0.00M;`
Total will increase when user enters items.

I need Form2 to access the variable `Total` from Form1 once the user is finished entering items and once the user selects the method to pay I can zero `Total` in Form2.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Form1 has a reference to Form2, you can just access it as a variable. Like this:

```
public class Form1
{
  public decimal Total {get; set;}
}

public class Form2
{
  public Form2()
  {
    var form1 = new Form1();
    form1.Show();

    ..later, after use has done some work and you need the variable
    var total = form1.Total;
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for showing another scenario for this problem and the proper solution.

Comment: @Steven P your post makes a little since to me. In your example do you create `public class Form1 { public decimal Total {get; set;} } ` anywhere in the program created by MSVS?

Comment: @Steven P What is the technical term or method name so I can do more research?

Comment: @ajaustin12 - Yes, if you right-cick your solution and choose "New Form...", it will create the Form1 class. It will be hard to post an answer unless you understand what classes and forms are. I'd suggest start with a basic Windows Forms Walkthrough like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9w2f38k.aspx. Until you can drag controls onto a designer, respond to events and set variables, you won't be able to achieve much.

Comment: @StevenP When I was asking the question I wasn't able to look at my program. I am starting to understand when I compare my program and your example.

Answer (score 1):

Create a static variable in another class or one of the classes. Static variables are accessed by everything. You need to make the variable generic/static. That is how I would do it.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that. I have read about classes several times and still don't understand them.

Comment: You have Form1 class. add a variable like "public static int Total { get; set; }. In the Form2, something happens you go: Form1.Total++. So the Form1's Total field is changed.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifiaction. Doing a little research on static variable/class

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the Form1 to your Form2 (in case you will need more variables):

```
public class Form2
{
    public Form1 form1 { get; set; };
}
```

I guess you should call Form2 from Form1, so you can do something like this:

```
public class Form1
{
    private void callForm2()
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.form1 = this;
        form2.Show();
    }
}
```

I don't recommend using static variables, because they can give you some problems in case you have more than 1 Form1 opened in your application.

Comment: @ajaustin12 what I'm trying to say that you could have 2 or more instances of `Form1`, `Form2` or `FormX`, and you should have control of the form instance (and its variables) that is actually showed to the user.

Comment: Thank you. The only thing that I am lost on is how and where do I create the class? It is late also so it is harder for me to follow right now.

Comment: @ajaustin12 I'll edit my post giving more info about the manipulation of Windows Forms. By the way, please tell me your Visual Studio version and the .Net Framework you are using, so I can post a better answer.

Comment: I am using MSVS 2010 Profesional. Not sure on the .Net. Not on PC with MSVS.

Comment: @ajaustin12 Ok thanks for the info I don't have VS 2010 so I must do some research first. Last question, are you writing a Windows Forms or WPF application?

Comment: I am using Windows Forms I believe because WPF doesn't sound familiar. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for such cases like this one - is to create 3rd class that represents the context of operations processed in these two forms. You can keep all the state you need to be shared in this class and pass it as a paramater from form to form. Or apply Singleton pattern that will allow to access the state from all of the forms you have.